# How to aggregate in the WHERE clause referencing the subquery from the FROM clause

Tags: join, mariadb, select, aggregate, window-functions

I got the following query so far:

```
SELECT q1.ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID, runtot
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID,
    SUM(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS runtot,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS rnum
  FROM multiqueue
  WHERE PublishedTS IS NULL
) AS q1
JOIN customers AS c1 ON q1.CustomerID=customers.ID
WHERE
  runtot < 2000 * c1.Priority / (SELECT SUM(Priority) FROM c1)
  OR rnum <= 1
```

It complains about a syntax error near `SELECT SUM(Priority) FROM c1`: neither `c1`, nor `q1` table can be referenced there.

So the following doesn't work either for computing the sum:

```
(SELECT SUM(Priority) FROM customers WHERE ID IN q1.CustomerID)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a sum of `customers.Priority` over just the customers selected in `q1`.

Could you please help me to fix the query if possible?

The DB is MariaDB v10.4.13 (you can also assume the latest version or even MySQL).

**UPDATE**: The following doesn't work either

```
SELECT q1.ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID, runtot
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID,
    SUM(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS runtot,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS rnum
  FROM multiqueue
  WHERE PublishedTS IS NULL
) AS q1
JOIN customers AS c1 ON q1.CustomerID=customers.ID
WHERE
  runtot < 2000 * c1.Priority / (SUM(Priority) OVER (PARTITION BY q1.CustomerID))
  OR rnum <= 1
```

MariaDB responds with `error 4015: Window function is allowed only in SELECT list and ORDER BY clause`.

**UPDATE2**: Table creation and population

```
CREATE TABLE `multiqueue` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `CustomerID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `Volume` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Content` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `PublishedTS` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `customers` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Priority` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO multiqueue VALUES
  (1, 1, 100, 'Content1', NULL),
  (2, 1, 200, 'Content2', NULL),
  (3, 1, 300, 'Content3', NULL),
  (4, 1, 400, 'Content4', NULL),
  (5, 1, 500, 'Content5', NULL),
  (6, 2, 100, 'Content6', NULL),
  (7, 2, 200, 'Content7', NULL),
  (8, 2, 300, 'Content8', NULL),
  (9, 2, 400, 'Content9', NULL),
  (10, 2, 500, 'Content10', NULL),
  (11, 1, 600, 'Content11', NULL)

INSERT INTO customers VALUES
  (1, 1000),
  (2, 500),
  (3, 100000)
```

I would like that the query produces approximately twice as much volume for customer #1 as for customer #2, and the total volume over both customers is about 2000.

**UPDATE3**: for the above inputs, the output can be:

```
ID    | Content   | Volume | CustomerID | runtot
------------------------------------------------
1     | Content1  | 100    | 1          | 100
2     | Content2  | 200    | 1          | 300
3     | Content3  | 300    | 1          | 600
4     | Content4  | 400    | 1          | 1000
6     | Content6  | 100    | 2          | 100
7     | Content7  | 200    | 2          | 300
8     | Content8  | 300    | 2          | 600
```

As we can see, the query must have selected a total volume of 1600 over both customers, approximately maintaining the proportion 1000:500 while keeping the total volume below 2000 if possible when selecting at least one row for every customer.

Comment: Use window version - `WHERE runtot < 2000 * customers.Priority / SUM(Priority) OVER (q1.CustomerID)`, it seems.

Comment: @Akina, I've edited the question to show how this fails too.

Comment: Create a fiddle or provide tables DDLs (as CREATE TABLE) and some sample data (as INSERT INTO). Show desired output for this data.

Comment: @Akina, please, see the edited question.

Comment: Your queries refers to `BlockToken` and `UrlCount` columns which are absent in tables DDLs. PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=35fdb05cf50b80d45f5a1cf231c2fd09

Comment: *I would like that the query produces approximately twice as much volume for customer #1 as for customer #2, and the total volume over both customers is about 2000.* Definite algorithm on definite source data must give accurate, not approximate, result. Show it as table-formed text.

Comment: @Akina, I've removed/renamed the data that leaked from the actual tables to the toy tables I'm posting here with just the relevant fields. As to the result, it's fine to be approximate for a definite algorithm. Let me try to show a table-formed text anyway...

Comment: *it's fine to be approximate for a definite algorithm.* It's because you have 2 optimizing criteria and not define their priority or relation. For example if 1:2 is prioritized criteria (the ratio difference from 1:2 must be minimized) then the solution where you take 3 rows for CustomerID=1 and 2 rows for CustomerID=2 may be preferred. And if 2000 total is prioritized criteria then the solution which takes rows 1,3,4,5 for CustomerID=1 and 1,2,4 (or 3,4) for CustomerID=2 may be preferred. You must form ONE criteria (which may combine your current two criteria).

Comment: @Akina, I don't need a total precision for either of the criteria. And I'm definitely not going to solve a knapsack problem in SQL for strict adherence to the ratio criterion.

Comment: The Question needs a better statement of the problem.  Is a particular customer treated as #1?  For the total of 2000: one place says "about 2000", another says "at most 2000".

Comment: @RickJames, customers are treated according to their priorities. I couldn't find the place where it says "at most".

Comment: @SergeRogatch - If there are 3 customers do you still use 2?  Or do you make a different proportion, say 800:600:400 ?

Comment: I try to pop at least one item for each customer from the queue. The proportions can be different, including 800:600:400, but it's more important that at least one item per customer is popped in each query. When there are more than 1 item per customer to pop, then I want to pop items according to the priorities of customers.

Answer (score 1):

[Your own solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/269658) might be suboptimal but I am not sure there is a way to solve the problem elegantly and/or efficiently without at least *some* redundancy.  I managed to avoid hitting the `customers` table more than once, but I still had to reference `multiqueue` twice.  This is the query I ended up with:

```
SELECT
  q.ID,
  q.Content,
  q.Volume,
  q.CustomerID,
  q.runtot
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID,
      SUM(Volume)  OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID ASC) AS runtot,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rnum
    FROM
      multiqueue
    WHERE
      PublishedTS IS NULL
  ) AS q
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      ci.ID, ci.Priority,
      SUM(ci.Priority) OVER () AS TotalPriority
    FROM
      customers AS ci
    WHERE
      EXISTS
      (
        SELECT * FROM multiqueue AS qi
        WHERE qi.PublishedTS IS NULL AND qi.CustomerID = ci.ID
      )
  ) AS c ON q.CustomerID = c.ID
WHERE
  q.runtot < 2000 * c.Priority / c.TotalPriority
  OR q.rnum <= 1
;
```

Basically, the join to `customers` is replaced with a join to a nested select from `customers` that incorporates both the `SUM(Priority)` calculation and the `EXISTS` check.  The check makes sure only the customers represented in `multiqueue` are returned, and as a result, the `Priority` total is calculated across those customers only.

The rest of the logic is, I hope, the same as in your own query.

You can test my solution in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=dc59deea9968490e651a041f6a507efc&hide=15) at [image: dbfiddle logo]db<>fiddle.uk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've measured: your query yields the same performance as mine on production data, but this performance is bad: ~`0.64` sec for `5744` records in `multiqueue` table and ~3 records in `customers` table. So the algorithm the DB uses is at least `O(N*N)` where `N` is the number of records in the `multiqueue` table.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT q1.ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID, runtot
> FROM (
>   SELECT ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID,
>     SUM(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS runtot,
>     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS rnum
>   FROM multiqueue
>   WHERE PublishedTS IS NULL
> ) AS q1
> JOIN customers AS c1 ON q1.CustomerID=c1.ID
> WHERE
>   runtot < 2000 * Priority / (SELECT SUM(Priority) FROM customers WHERE ID = CustomerID)
>   OR rnum <= 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Content   | Volume | CustomerID | runtot
> -: | :-------- | -----: | ---------: | -----:
>  1 | Content1  |    100 |          1 |    100
>  2 | Content2  |    200 |          1 |    300
>  3 | Content3  |    300 |          1 |    600
>  4 | Content4  |    400 |          1 |   1000
>  5 | Content5  |    500 |          1 |   1500
>  6 | Content6  |    100 |          2 |    100
>  7 | Content7  |    200 |          2 |    300
>  8 | Content8  |    300 |          2 |    600
>  9 | Content9  |    400 |          2 |   1000
> 10 | Content10 |    500 |          2 |   1500
> ```

> ```
> SELECT q1.ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID, runtot
> FROM (
>   SELECT ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID,
>     SUM(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS runtot,
>     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS rnum
>   FROM multiqueue
>   WHERE PublishedTS IS NULL
> ) AS q1
> JOIN customers AS c1 ON q1.CustomerID=c1.ID
> WHERE
>   runtot < 2000 * Priority / (SELECT SUM(Priority) FROM customers)
>   OR rnum <= 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Content  | Volume | CustomerID | runtot
> -: | :------- | -----: | ---------: | -----:
>  1 | Content1 |    100 |          1 |    100
>  2 | Content2 |    200 |          1 |    300
>  3 | Content3 |    300 |          1 |    600
>  4 | Content4 |    400 |          1 |   1000
>  6 | Content6 |    100 |          2 |    100
>  7 | Content7 |    200 |          2 |    300
>  8 | Content8 |    300 |          2 |    600
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=58560875838035cbce76f60f28c4b93f)*

Depending what information you want, you can select the max(ID) for every customerID(GROUP BY)

Comment: It's wrong to select into the denominator just the priority of a single customer. I was trying to select the sum of priorities of all customers who have an active row in the queue.

Comment: Then remove the WHERE Clause in the subselect, for me this makes more sense.

Comment: Without the `WHERE` clause the subselect would aggregate over all the customers, including customers who do not have an active row (request) in the queue. There may be 100 customers, of them only 2 have simultaneous requests. If I aggregate the priority over all 100 customers, I would fetch a volume of ~20 instead of 2000 from the DB.

Comment: The frist query makes sense to me, you said no it has to be overall all, ok i changed teh qiey to do exactly that, but this diesn't m,any sense at all

Comment: Perhaps it will be more clear if you look at the query that achieves the goal in a suboptimal way ( https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/269658/144167 ) and try to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a query that achieves the goal, though it might be far suboptimal:

```
SELECT p1.ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID, runtot
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Content, Volume, CustomerID,
    SUM(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS runtot,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ID) AS rnum
  FROM multiqueue
  WHERE PublishedTS IS NULL
) AS p1
JOIN customers AS c1 ON p1.CustomerID=c1.ID
WHERE
  runtot < 2000 * c1.Priority / (
    SELECT SUM(Priority) FROM customers AS c2
    WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM multiqueue AS p2
      WHERE p2.CustomerID=c2.ID
        AND p2.PublishedTS IS NULL
    )
  )
  OR rnum <= 1
```

Verified at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=e3bd1347b596e722e506f9ce75da0505).

Comment: your query **still** doesn't work, and gives back the same result(after fixuig it). you hole change with thewhere clause doesn't add or remove anything.and is in my opinio not needed

Comment: @nbk, I've fixed the query (it's hard to maintain a working query while moving from production to sandbox). To see the point, you can add customer #3 with `Priority`=100000 . Then with the first your query you would be always selecting 2000 of volume for each customer, and with your second query you would be always selecting just 1 row per customer #1 and #2.